# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ModelController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, wicked-gem

Working in a Rails app with a model called Shootings. It has several fields in it, so I'm using the Wicked gem to collect them in several steps.

I'm able to create Shooting records correctly, and I'm able to start the Wicked wizard correctly if I manually type the path. However I'm not able to set the redirection after the Shooting creationg with the first step of the wizard.

I get this error in the build_controller.rb once I try to redirect after I create the shooting, to the first step of the wizard

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shootings/build", :shooting_id=>#<Shooting id: 100, title: "cwe AVER", created_at: "2021-02-13 20:01:26.212909000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-02-13 20:01:26.212909000 +0000", user_id: 1, typeshooting: nil, numberimages: nil, proservices: nil, goals: nil, status: nil>}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'll let the code speak for itself

shootings_controller.rb

```
class ShootingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shooting, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /shootings/new
  def new
    @shooting = Shooting.new
  end

  # POST /shootings or /shootings.json
  def create
    @shooting = Shooting.new(shooting_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shooting.save
        format.html { redirect_to shooting_build_path(@shooting), notice: "Shooting was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shooting }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @shooting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shootings/1 or /shootings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shooting.update(shooting_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shooting, notice: "Shooting was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shooting }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @shooting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

build_controler.rb (in controllers > shootings)

```
class Shootings::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :add_typeshooting, :add_numberimages, :add_proservices, :add_goals

  def show
    @shooting = Shooting.find(params[:shooting_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @shooting = Shooting.find(params[:shooting_id])
    params[:shooting][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @shooting.update(shooting_params)
    render_wizard @shooting
  end

  def create
    @shooting = Shooting.create
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, shooting_id: @shooting.id)
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard options = nil, params =  {}
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thanks for your shooting'
  end
  
  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def shooting_params
    params.require(:shooting).permit(:title, :user_id, :typeshooting, :numberimages, :proservices, :goals)
  end

  def set_shooting
    @shooting = Shooting.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :shootings do
    resources :build, controller: 'shootings/build'
  end
  resources :photos
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "shootings#index"
end
```

and rail routes

```
shooting_build_index GET    /shootings/:shooting_id/build(.:format)                                                           shootings/build#index
                                         POST   /shootings/:shooting_id/build(.:format)                                                           shootings/build#create
                      new_shooting_build GET    /shootings/:shooting_id/build/new(.:format)                                                       shootings/build#new
                     edit_shooting_build GET    /shootings/:shooting_id/build/:id/edit(.:format)                                                  shootings/build#edit
                          shooting_build GET    /shootings/:shooting_id/build/:id(.:format)                                                       shootings/build#show
                                         PATCH  /shootings/:shooting_id/build/:id(.:format)                                                       shootings/build#update
                                         PUT    /shootings/:shooting_id/build/:id(.:format)                                                       shootings/build#update
                                         DELETE /shootings/:shooting_id/build/:id(.:format)                                                       shootings/build#destroy
                               shootings GET    /shootings(.:format)                                                                              shootings#index
                                         POST   /shootings(.:format)                                                                              shootings#create
                            new_shooting GET    /shootings/new(.:format)                                                                          shootings#new
                           edit_shooting GET    /shootings/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                     shootings#edit
                                shooting GET    /shootings/:id(.:format)                                                                          shootings#show
                                         PATCH  /shootings/:id(.:format)                                                                          shootings#update
                                         PUT    /shootings/:id(.:format)                                                                          shootings#update
                                         DELETE /shootings/:id(.:format)                                                                          shootings#destroy
```

shootings form

```
<%= form_with(model: shooting) do |form| %>
<% if shooting.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(shooting.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shooting from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
        <% shooting.errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Seems in your wicked next step you are not creating correct url, you have to add /:id in end of url but when it happen with wicked it is not populating properly `missing required keys: [:id]` it is telling you that you don't have id in your url. I will compare url being redirected and the one you doing manually and see difference.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar in my shootings_controller.rb, I edited the create method, otherwise it will return the same error and won't allow me to create the record. Right now is format.html { redirect_to @ shooting, notice: "Shooting was successfully created." } and it redirects back to the Shooting show view (/shootings/ID) And the wicked URL (where I want to redirect it) is /shootings/ID/build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change following url, and it is working

```
format.html {
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Shooting was successfully created.'
  redirect_to shooting_build_index_path(@shooting) 
 }
```

Or rails way

```
format.html do
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Shooting was successfully created.'
  redirect_to shooting_build_index_path(@shooting) 
 end
```

But personally I think it should work like above but some how it is not working.